# Class 'App Http Controllers Auth User' not found

Tags: php, laravel

I'm getting this error while trying to integrate Google login on my Laravel app:

> Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\User' not found

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class SocialiteController extends Controller
{
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
}


public function redirectToGoogle()
{
    return \Socialite::driver('google')->redirect();
}


public function handleGoogleCallback(Request $request)
{
    $googleUser = \Socialite::driver('google')->stateless()->user();

    $user = \User::whereGoogleId($googleUser->id)->first();

    if ($user) {
        Auth::login($user);

        return LoginController::authenticated($request, $user);
    } else {
        list($first_name, $last_name) = explode(' ', $googleUser->name);
        // signup
        $input = [
            'first_name' => $first_name,
            'last_name' => $last_name,
            'email' => $googleUser->email,
        ];

        $request->session()->flash('google_token', $googleUser->accessToken);

        return RegisterController::showRegistrationForm()->withInput($input)->with;
    }
}
```

also,i don't know the full namespace for USER
I'm new to this .

If you could give a working tutorial,i'll appreciate.
Could you please advise me on solution?

Comment: Use the full namespace for User

Comment: try `\User::`. Please edit your question and paste your code, don't link images of code. And please remove the link to your site, is not necessary.

Comment: now showing "Class 'User' not found"

Comment: where is your User class file?

Comment: may i know what's the file name for User class?

Comment: where is the file User.php?

Comment: It's on Model under app folder

Comment: please try `\Model\User::`

Comment: it's now showing a new error. 'Client error: `POST https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: { "error": "invalid_grant", "error_description": "Bad Request" }'

Comment: Nice now the user class is found, but that is another question.

Answer (score 0):

## Update

<s>If you are intending to use the default `User` model provided by Laravel, the `User` class should be stored in the `/app` directory (check it first).</s>

Given the fact that your User model is inside the `app/Model` directory, update your code like this:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

// some imports..

use App\Model\User; // <------

class SocialiteController extends Controller
{

    // some code..

    public function handleGoogleCallback(Request $request)
    {

        // more code..

        $user = User::whereGoogleId($googleUser->id)->first();
//              ^^^^
        // ...
    }
}
```

---

Note: the following error shown:

> 400 Bad Request response:
>
> ```
> {
>     "error": "invalid_grant",
>     "error_description": "Bad Request"
> }
> ```

This has to do with your Google app keys. This is part of a different question.

Comment: still `Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\User' not found`

Comment: @HALLOweEN do not forget to include the `use` statement signalled at the top.

Comment: is there any working tutorial to integrate google login you can provide?

Comment: @HALLOweEN Just google it, mate. Note that the Google+ API stop working a couple months ago, so check an updated or newer tutorial. There are several out there. Have a good day ;)

Answer (score 0):

If the `User` model file is located under a folder named **Model** yuo have to call the fully qualified name of the `User` class or add a `use` statement to your code, i.e.:

```
$user = \Model\User::whereGoogleId($googleUser->id)->first();

// or this solution
use \Model\User;
....
$user = User::whereGoogleId($googleUser->id)->first();
```

Comment: please accept and upvote an answer if you found it useful